# Moments of Fourier transform of a polygon

Tags: geometry, fourier-transform, polygons

I am working on the Fourier transform of a polygon. Based on a publication of Shung Wu Lee I have the following formula for the Fourier transform:

$$S(u,v) =
\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i \omega\cdot\gamma_n}\left[\frac{\alpha_n\times\alpha_{n-1}}{(\omega\cdot\alpha_n)(\omega\cdot\alpha_{n-1})}\right]
$$

where $\omega$, $\alpha_n$ and $\gamma_n$ are all vectors in 2D space with

$$\alpha_n = \frac{\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_{n}}{|\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_{n}|}$$

The vectors $\gamma_n$ are the vertex of the polygon and in the formula the indices are meant modulus N so that $\gamma_0 = \gamma_N$ and $\gamma_{N+1}=\gamma_1$.

If we develop the Taylor series expansion of the exponential and we get the zero-th order term we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\alpha_n\times\alpha_{n-1}}{(\omega\cdot\alpha_n)(\omega\cdot\alpha_{n-1})}
$$

which seems to be zero for any $\omega$ but for the moment I haven't figured out a proof.

Can someone point out a possible proof or otherwise give some hint about how to proceed.

I guess also that the first order term of the expansion is also zero and the second order term should be the oriented area of the polygon.

Comment: When you say " but for the moment I haven't figured out a proof" is it a pun on the word "moment" ? I don't understand what you mean by "moment" in your title ?

Comment: @JeanMarie when I way "for the moment" I mean just "up to now". Otherwise you are right, when I use the word moments it is ambiguous. I mean that each coefficient of the Taylor series of the exponential produce a moment. The word "moment" was inspired by [Moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Definition).

Comment: 1) Could you give us more information about the article of Shung Wu Lee ? 2) A basic question: do we agree that the Discrete Fourier Transform you use operates on $N$ dimensional vectors where $N$ the number of vertices of the polygon ?

Comment: 1) Lee, S.-W. and Mittra, R., “Fourier transform of a polygonal shape function and its application in electromagnetics”, IEEE Transactions on Antennas and Propagation, vol. 31, pp. 99–103, 1983. doi:10.1109/TAP.1983.1142981. 2) The vectors are 2-dimensional as I wrote they belong to a 2D space. It is not a discrete Fourier Transform but the Fourier Transform of functions that is equal to 1 inside the polygon and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: Do you mean that the polygon is a set, say, of black pixels with a white surrounding ? But, besides, its boundary has been sufficiently well extracted that we know with enough precision its vertices, right ? A little remark: when I see the publication date, 1983, it looks fairly old, isn't it ? I know that it's not an absolute criteria, but at that time, for example computing a  2D FFT of a $512 \times 512$ image could take hours on a PC... Clever methods had been imagined at that time to shorten the computation time... and these methods are not necessarily interesting now on...

Comment: Yes, you can think of the polygon as a set of black pixel if you want but what we really consider is a function that is constant in the polygon, to the value one, and zero outside. It is the equivalent of the step-function by in 2D for a polygon. If you are interested the problem arise when applying the RCWA technique to solve the Maxwell Equation for a plane wave incident in a diffraction grating. The diffraction grating can be thought as a dielectric constant that is changing abruptly between to values based on the design of the grating.

Comment: As for the FFT, you are right, it is so fast in modern computer that is rarely an issue but my co-worker insisted on computing the Fourier transform analytically. I was nevertheless intrigued by the problem because of the simplicity and the elegance of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and interesting answers.

Comment: Connected: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00255.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The article of Joachin Wuttke answers to all my questions and much more.

Comment: Very happy that it has been useful for you. Good luck for your future research!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the way to proof the value given above is zero for any $\omega$. I don't give here the full details but I proceeded in the following way:

- show it is zero for a triangle
- for induction, it is true for a polygon with n vertex, add a new vertex and show it is still true

To show it is zero for a triangle I expanded everything in terms of $\gamma_n$ and then I noted that:

$$(\gamma_3-\gamma_2)\times(\gamma_2 - \gamma_1) =(\gamma_1-\gamma_3)\times(\gamma_3 - \gamma_2)$$

because both sides are equal to twice the area of the oriented triangle. The same is true for the other permutations of the indices.

To show that it remains true when a triangle is added in a polygon is quite easy if expanded in term of the function:

$$t(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)=\frac{\alpha_i\times\alpha_j}{(\omega\cdot\alpha_i)(\omega\cdot\alpha_j)}$$

It is enough to write the expression and note that the term corresponding to the side in common between the triangle and the polygon vanish because the function $t$ is anti-symmetric.

Otherwise, for the terms arising from the first and second terms of the Taylor expansion of the exponential, I don't know but I suspect they can be shown to be equal to zero and the area of the triangle respectively using a similar approach.